# trying to combine two nested queries for efficiency

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have two nested queries, and the second is run as I iterate through the results of the first.  I'd love to have the MySQL server do this work instead of PHP, but I can't figure out how to combine these two.

the first query:

```
SELECT post_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'size' THEN meta_value END) size,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'adlink' THEN meta_value END) adlink,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'frontpage' THEN meta_value END) frontpage,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'expiration' THEN meta_value END) expiration,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'image1' THEN meta_value END) image1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'image2' THEN meta_value END) image2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'image3' THEN meta_value END) image3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'image4' THEN meta_value END) image4,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'iframe' THEN meta_value END) iframe,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'location' THEN meta_value END) location,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'sublocation' THEN meta_value END) sublocation
    FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id in 
      (SELECT post_id from wp_postmeta 
       WHERE meta_value LIKE 'Run Of Site') GROUP BY Post_id
```

Then, iterating through the results, we get images from another table, as 'image1', etc., are only post id numbers in the first set of results:

```
SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta 
   WHERE post_id IN
     (SELECT meta_value from wp_postmeta 
      WHERE post_id = " . $row{'post_id'} ." AND meta_key like 'image%')
```

HERE's the whole code to see PHP iteration (I KNOW it needs better formatting for readbility):

```
$rosads = mysql_query("SELECT post_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'size' THEN meta_value END) size,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'adlink' THEN meta_value END) adlink,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'frontpage' THEN meta_value END) frontpage,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'expiration' THEN meta_value END) expiration,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'image1' THEN meta_value END) image1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'image2' THEN meta_value END) image2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'image1' THEN meta_value END) image3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'image2' THEN meta_value END) image4,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'iframe' THEN meta_value END) iframe,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'location' THEN meta_value END) location,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'sublocation' THEN meta_value END) sublocation
    FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id in (SELECT post_id from wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value LIKE 'Run Of Site') GROUP BY Post_id");
if (!$rosads) { // add this check.
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rosads)) {   // #########  ITERATE THROUGH THE LIST

        if ($row{'size'} == "Premium"){
            if ($row{'iframe'}){
                $premium = $premium . '<div name="PREMIUM'.$row{'post_id'}.'" style="float:left;">'.$row{'iframe'}.'</div>'."\n";
            }else{
                $images = mysql_query("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta where post_id IN(SELECT meta_value from wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = " . $row{'post_id'} ." AND meta_key like 'image%')");
                $premium = $premium . "<div name=\"".$row{'post_id'}."\" class=\"multipleslides\" >";
                while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($images)) {
                    $premium = $premium . "\t<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"" . $row{'adlink'} ."\"><img src=\"/wp-content/uploads/" .$row2{'meta_value'} ."\"></a>\r\n";
                }
                $premium = $premium . "</div><br>";
            }
        /* ### TEST STUFF ####
        echo $row{'post_id'} . ", " . $row{'size'} . ", " . $row{'adlink'} . ", " . $row{'frontpage'} . ", " . $row{'expiration'} . ", " . $row{'image1'} . ", " . $row{'image2'} . ", " . $row{'image3'} . ", " . $row{'image4'} . ", " . 1$row{'location'} . ", " . $row{'sublocation'} . ", " . $row{'iframe'} . "<hr>";
        */
        } // ###### END THIS ITERATION ####
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Lots of people on SO understand the WordPress schema, so it might help to state your intention.

Comment: Trying to create a custom advertisement plugin using the existing wp_postmeta table and it's structure - THAT was my first fault... would have been easier to create a new table... :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your query as a column also but make sure your subquery should return one record for safe side i have added `LIMIT 1` in the subquery or if there are morethan 1 result you can remove the limit and can use `GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value)` but baware it has a default limit of 1024 characters

```
SELECT wpm.post_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wpm.meta_key = 'size' THEN wpm.meta_value END) size,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wpm.meta_key = 'adlink' THEN wpm.meta_value END) adlink,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wpm.meta_key = 'frontpage' THEN wpm.meta_value END) frontpage,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wpm.meta_key = 'expiration' THEN wpm.meta_value END) expiration,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wpm.meta_key = 'image1' THEN wpm.meta_value END) image1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wpm.meta_key = 'image2' THEN wpm.meta_value END) image2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wpm.meta_key = 'image3' THEN wpm.meta_value END) image3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wpm.meta_key = 'image4' THEN wpm.meta_value END) image4,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wpm.meta_key = 'iframe' THEN wpm.meta_value END) iframe,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wpm.meta_key = 'location' THEN wpm.meta_value END) location,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wpm.meta_key = 'sublocation' THEN wpm.meta_value END) sublocation,
(
SELECT 
  meta_value 
FROM
  wp_postmeta 
WHERE post_id IN 
  (SELECT 
    meta_value 
  FROM
    wp_postmeta 
  WHERE post_id = wpm. post_id
    AND meta_key LIKE 'image%')
LIMIT 1) images       

    FROM wp_postmeta wpm WHERE wpm.post_id IN 
      (SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta 
       WHERE meta_value LIKE 'Run Of Site') GROUP BY wpm.post_id
```

For the `group_concat()`

```
(
SELECT 
 GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value)
FROM
  wp_postmeta 
WHERE post_id IN 
  (SELECT 
    meta_value 
  FROM
    wp_postmeta 
  WHERE post_id = wpm. post_id
    AND meta_key LIKE 'image%')
) images
```

Comment: Well, that got me an interesting, if cryptic response: 
`Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_' at line 13`

Comment: Show me the whole query your are trying i guess there is something missing after `sublocation` may be a comma

Comment: I guess, ideally, I'm trying to get that query inserted where image1, image2, etc., are being formatted into columns - (the `MAX()` line), so that I get the image url from the 2nd query instead of the id from the 1st.

Comment: I'm going to post the WHOLE piece above, where you can see formatting.

Comment: @DavidMcClave can you add the table definitions and sample dataset at [*sqlfiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: @DavidMcClave your question states that you need to combine two queries so this is it my answer shows you the way in  single you have the images for the records returned an you not used the query properly so thats y you got the error ,still waiting for the fiddle demo

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49326/discussion-between-m-khalid-junaid-and-david-mcclave)

Comment: @DavidMcClave see [*this fiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23c1c/6) is that you want although i have removed the where clause its filtering out all the results

Comment: @DavidMcClave see my comments in [*chat*](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49326/discussion-between-m-khalid-junaid-and-david-mcclave)

Answer (score 1):

To improve efficiency, replace the `IN (subquery)` with equivalent join operations, and ensure that you have suitable indexes in place.

In the first query, replace this:

```
    FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id in 
      (SELECT post_id from wp_postmeta 
       WHERE meta_value LIKE 'Run Of Site') GROUP BY Post_id
```

with this:

```
   FROM wp_postmeta m
   JOIN ( SELECT r.post_id 
            FROM wp_postmeta r
           WHERE r.meta_value LIKE 'Run Of Site'
          GROUP BY r.post_id
        ) q
     ON q.post_id = m.post_id 
  GROUP BY m.post_id
```

**AND** change the `post_id` reference in the SELECT list to `m.post_id` (to avoid an "ambiguous column" reference error.)

For the second query, replace the "IN (subquery)" with a JOIN operation:

```
SELECT t.meta_value
  FROM wp_postmeta t
  JOIN ( SELECT q.meta_value
           FROM wp_postmeta q 
          WHERE q,meta_key LIKE 'image%'
            AND q.post_id = " . $row{'post_id'} ."
       ) s
    ON s.meta_value = t.meta_value
 ORDER BY t.meta_value
```

---

Combining the two queries is problematic because the second query can return more than one row that matches on post_id.

To get result set returned, we need to define what that result set is going to look like.

There's three general approaches. Briefly,

One way is to "repeat" the values returned by the first query, but that doesn't look like a good fit with your current code. The "fetch next" would need to check if the post_id had already been processed, and ignore the duplicate values. (This is the approach used by several ORM frameworks to improve efficiency; those have a code layer that strips out the duplicates, and creates the distinct objects.)

Another way is to return a fixed number of values from the second query, each as a column in the second. Note that the SQL SELECT statement has to define the number of columns to return and the datatype of each. That can't be changed dynamically when the query runs. If we can specify a finite upper bound of the number of rows to return, then we can craft SQL text to accomplish this, though the resulting statement can be a bit daunting, and there are some performance concerns.

The most convenient way to return a "set" of values is to return them as a single string, with delimiters. The MySQL `GROUP_CONCAT` function is a very handy way of doing that, with some limitations. First, we have to have a delimiter between the values; the default delimiter is a comma, but any character can be used (the "pipe" character seems to be pretty popular... to avoid ambiguity, we have to guarantee that the delimiter character does not appear in the values being concatenated together. The other limit is the size of the returned by the function; the maximum size is limited by the MySQL `max_allowed_packet` variable.

---

Comment: Very nice, and VERY thorough answer! Thanks a bunch!